# window.onload function only on the first loading page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to attempt a page loading only for the first loading screen. This means when I load the page, I could have a preloading screen, but not on every page load or reload (not on the inside pages).

How could I use

```
window.onload
```

function to achieve this?

Could anyone suggest?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<script>
   if (!localStorage['done']) {
       localStorage['done'] = 'yes';
       myFunction();
   }
</script>
```

Comment: and to set it false inside myFunction

Answer (score 0):

If you set your loading design to cover the page and then simply using Jquery you can hide it. If your loading the new pages 'inline' without refreshing the window then you will only see your loading page when you open the site originally

```
document.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(document.readyState=="complete") {
                    $(".loading").hide();
                }};
```